# Java unicast and multicast performance

Tags: java, udp, cluster-computing, high-availability

Hi: Has someone compared Java unicast and multicast implementation against those written in C? which programming language give better performance? If I am going to implement a demon thread and constantly poll two cluster units in order to achieve High Availability.

Comment: daemon,wrong typing. a tine thread wake up every 0.25 sec and check if every units in the cluster work fine or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be network bound, so the choice of programming language won't make much difference. You'll find networking code much easier to write in Java rather than grappling with the C API.

Comment: what about write a heartbeat application in Java, rather than in C.

Comment: @user84592 what difference would that make? And why would that be performance-critical in the first place?

Comment: In C, some open source project says it could notice some unit faliure after 0.5 sec. What about I write it in Java. Is the performace would be the issue?

Comment: @user84592 half a second is an eternity on a computer.